# Geospatial mapping using ggplot faceting in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geospatial, spatial, facet-wrap

I have a `Watershed` that has 33 `subbasins`. I wasn't able to come up with a code to draw a reproducible `shapefile` for the catchment so i am attaching my [Shapefile](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1APTrtIVgmRV0lOLVMNeLVJHct6JiSgfs). I have `four models` that generate `Evapotranspiration (ET)` data for the years `2005-2008`. I would like to compare the four models products of each year using `ggplot` `faceting` functionality. I tried a few things (see my sample code) but couldn't succeeded. I would appreciate a way forward.

```
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)

shape <- read_sf(dsn = ".", layer = "Watershed")


ETM1 = data.frame(Subbasin = 1:33, Yr2005 = runif(33, 500,700), Yr2006 = runif(33, 600,750), Yr2007 = runif(33, 450,750),
                  Yr2008 = runif(33, 550,800), Model = rep("M1", 33))

ETM2 = data.frame(Subbasin = 1:33, Yr2005 = runif(33, 600,750), Yr2006 = runif(33, 550,750), Yr2007 = runif(33, 600,750),
                  Yr2008 = runif(33, 700,800), Model = rep("M2", 33))

ETM3 = data.frame(Subbasin = 1:33, Yr2005 = runif(33, 500,750), Yr2006 = runif(33, 650,750), Yr2007 = runif(33, 700,750),
                  Yr2008 = runif(33, 500,800), Model = rep("M3", 33))

ETM4 = data.frame(Subbasin = 1:33, Yr2005 = runif(33, 400,750), Yr2006 = runif(33, 450,750), Yr2007 = runif(33, 300,750),
                  Yr2008 = runif(33, 400,800), Model = rep("M4", 33))

ETData = rbind(ETM1,ETM2,ETM3,ETM4)
Combine = gather(ETData, key = "Variable", value = "Value", -c("Model","Subbasin"))

SpData = merge(shape, Combine, by='Subbasin')

ggplot() + 
  geom_polygon(SpData, aes(x = Lat, y = Long_, fill = Value))+
  facet_wrap(~Model, nrow = 4, ncol = 4)
```

here is a picture of my shapefile that i draw using `plot(shape$geometry)`
[image]

Here is an approximate `figure` that i would like to construct, though it has only 3 rows. 
[image]

I made a figure (hand drawn) that reflects my ultimate goal- each oval shape (sort of) represent my `Catchment shapefile` with division as `subbasins`. I apologies for my bad drawing.
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were quite close to the solution. Your final data contains everything to get your plot.

Basically, you can use `facet_grid` to separate both "Year" and "Model" variables and `geom_sf` that will use the column "geometry" of your dataset to plot the shape (more informations here: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/ggsf.html). Passing the value as a filling into the `aes` will make the rest.

Here, I used `scale_fill_gradient` to set the color and few functions to get the plot as close as your desired plot:

```r
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = SpData, aes(fill = Value))+
  facet_grid(Variable~Model)+
  scale_fill_gradient(name =  "Evapotranspiration (ET)", low = "green", high = "red",
                      limits = c(300,900), 
                      breaks = c(300, 500, 700, 900))+
  theme_void()+
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you- I am learning quite some tricks from the solutions you have provided to some of my questions.

Comment: You're welcome ! Happy to help ;) (I'm learning too by trying to answer your questions using your example ;))